# tcpdump packets length mismatch

Tags: networking, http, tcpdump

I'm trying to find out why my application has a huge network traffic, particularly, the outbound traffic.
Researching the issue, I found a number such packets where length mismatches the difference between sequence numbers (see the example below):

len = 47688 - 47195 = 463, which is exactly the length of the response.
But `length` indicates that the length is over 40MB, which is an odd size for a redirect response. I'd expect those numbers to be the same.

What can it mean and how is it possible?

The command:

```
sudo tcpdump -nn -A 'port 80 and src host 172.25.2.20'
```

An example of suspicious packet:

```
22:01:08.829010 IP 172.25.2.20.80 > 172.25.2.7.5353: Flags [P.], seq 47195:47688, ack 73973, win 1389, options [nop,nop,TS val 179483194 ecr 867273499], length 49321584 update+% [b2&3=0x2f31] [8243a] [11825q] [12338n] [8262au][|domain]
....m^a.....!K|@..............P.....,s.
..:3...HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 02 Mar 2018 22:01:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=2
Etag: "fdGd1xOMm9JndEsCTLr-3gnaNW-dTGhoVi9Lb_rtYA0="
Location: https://match.sharethrough.com/sync/v1?source_id=882ef0fa44a9ae20d4421c83&source_user_id=fdGd1xOMm9JndEsCTLr-3gnaNW-dTGhoVi9Lb_rtYA0%3D
Set-Cookie: pl_user_id=fdGd1xOMm9JndEsCTLr-3gnaNW-dTGhoVi9Lb_rtYA0=; Domain=powerlinks.com; Max-Age=315360000
```

**UPD:** As it happens in AWS Cloud, I've asked them to revise the bills and explain the charges which were based on Network Usage. I'm waiting for their response.

Comment: If you are asking something about the output of a command, please include the command with the exact parameters you used.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, thanks! I've updated the question!

Comment: Could you explain better the length mismatch? I have got a hunch, but not sure.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I added some explanation to the question to make it clearer. Looking forward to hearing your thoughts :)

Comment: My first thought was that you were missing a `tcpdump` option, but it is not that. Maybe TSO, not sure.

Comment: I'd like to "blame" TSO. Then, I'd like to see what else is sent in the responses, as it's extremely odd having 301 redirect with a size of 50MB.